# Expand rows with multiple information into unique rows with a single information

Tags: r, duplicates, expand

I have a dataset in R which looks like that:

| Id | Pb_cit |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2000(19)|5600(24) |
| 2 | 3000(79)|87600(198) |

I would like to expand the rows in order to get a dataset that looks like that:

| Id | Pb_id | Cites |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2000 | 19 |
| 1 | 5600 | 24 |
| 2 | 3000 | 79 |
| 2 | 87600 | 198 |

Any help would be very appreciated!

Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a way with `separate_rows` and `extract`:

```r
library(tidyr)
dat %>% 
  separate_rows(Pb_cit, sep = "\\|") %>% 
  extract(Pb_cit, into = c("Pb_id", "Cites"), "(\\d+)\\((\\d+)\\)")

#     Id Pb_id Cites
#1     1 2000  19   
#2     1 5600  24   
#3     2 3000  79   
#4     2 87600 198
```